# car drives in direction of already defined path, how can I control this path using usual controls

Tags: game-engine

I rig a car with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_bgexISCSA and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JOp2WJvIkw. The direction of driving depends on the already defined path. I want to make a game using this. How can I modify the path using the usual controls (left arrow and right arrow for turning, up arrow for accelerate)

Comment: Assign vertices of the path to hook empties?

Comment: the car moves forward, so then the path is going to be very long?

Comment: I mean that the empties move forward along with the car, but the already defined path is finite, so we have to append it?

Comment: Do you want to control it in realtime?

Comment: yes, because I want to make a game, so I thought of the path that could behave as a snake in a snake game http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32101/make-path-move-like-snake-in-snake-game

Comment: If you want to make it in a game, consider using physics

Comment: But, can I use the same rig?

Comment: Maybe not, however i don't think using a curve will work very well for you